# Bulma modal card view on mobile browser issue

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bulma

I'm been trying to use Bulma's modal card to develop some features, but when I open a relatively large size modal card popup, and if the browser is showing tool bars, it will cover some view of the modal (usually will cover up the buttons and make it difficult to tap on using finger).

Just like this:
[image]

it depends on the content, but when there are input fields inside the modal then it is some what difficult to disable the bottom toolbar using your finger. Is it possible to make it resize a bit upon the Browser UI changes?

Comment: Not sure with bulma, but if you have this <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in header it should take care of autoscaling,
make sure shrink-to-fit=no is removed if present.

Comment: @karthik tried, didnt work